# How to access ruby from Ubuntu bash for windows

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu

I started ROR development on windows using Ubuntu bash. For now it was going well but when i tried to debug ruby on window using Rubymine it said no ruby SDK specified. How can i access the ruby sdk from ubuntu bash?

Answer (score 0):

In resume: maybe **Rubymine** is a **windows-program** which is not aware of the ruby (ROR) environment installed inside the windows10-WSL.

In more detail: before windows10 (with winxp, win7, etc) ubuntu and linux programs could not be installed inside windows. So in those cases, if you needed to use a linux program, you could download virtualbox, create a separate VirtualMAchine, install there your Ubuntu and then inside install the ubuntu programs (Ruby, ROR, etc)

With windows10, there is a new feature called *WSL - Windows Subsystem for Linux*, which allows a ubuntu system to be installed inside window. It uses some hidden virtualization/conversion to make it transparent for the user, and so any ubunut command can be run from the windows-console, without VirtualBox nor VirtualMachine - its looks as if windows could execute linux programs natively (but its just an ilusion though)

It looks like you installed ROR in the WSL-Ubuntu. And then installed *RubyMine* on windows. And then Rubymine tried to find the ROR-things in the windows directories but it did not found any. I guess its because Rubymine is not prepared to search within the WSL-Ubuntu for the ROR-things and so fails.

My second guess, is that the easiest solution could be to avoid using WSL-Ubuntu (as other programs wont be ready for it - currently it looks more of an experiment, not a real stable standard). And instead, try to do it all inside a Virtual-Box VirtualMachine, where you install ubuntu, all the programs you want (and they will run fine there), and avoid the WSL-mix. Even if this way requires a bit more work in the start - to prepare the VirtualBox and VM with ubuntu (youtube has many tutorials for this) - it will definitely save you time/headaches in the long-run when you need to install additional library/program/gem for your ROR environment